# how to accept accumulated applications aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

The problem is that the application acceptance bot was disabled for some time due to the fact that the server crashed, and now there are more than 100 applications accumulated there and the bot did not accept them at launch. It only accepts new applications. Please tell me how to accept the accumulated applications

```
async def approve_request(chat_join: ChatJoinRequest, bot: Bot):
    msg1 = "text"
    conn = create_conn()
    create_users_table(conn)
    if not user_exists(conn, chat_join.from_user.id):
        add_user(conn, chat_join.from_user.id)

    sent_message = await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_join.from_user.id, text=msg1)
    await chat_join.approve()





async def start():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format="%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] -  %(name)s - "
                               "(%(filename)s).%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) - %(message)s"
                        )
    await bot.delete_webhook()  # add this line
    dp.chat_join_request.register(approve_request, F.chat.id ==CHANNEL_ID)
    router.include_router(mailing_photo_router)
    router.include_router(mailing_video_router)
    dp.include_router(router)
    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error(f'[Exception] - {ex}', exc_info=True)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with contextlib.suppress(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        asyncio.run(start())
```

I have no idea what to do, there is not much information on the Internet about bots that accept applications. The aiogram documentation is quite difficult for me to understand. People have ads running, and I'm setting them up like that. If anyone has encountered such a problem, please direct me in the right direction

Comment: I was answered by one developer who deals with audiogram. If the bot "missed" the request, then there is no way to get it anymore. Now only with your hands or userbot